# What is the technical difference between webRTC communication and VoIP

Tags: webrtc, voip

can anyone help me what is the technical difference between WebRTC communication and the VoIP communication?

Comment: WebRTC is a kind of VoIP.

Comment: `web real time communication` v.s. `voice over internet protocol`. voip's a fairly generic acronym mostly. webrtc is more for any kind of browser-to-browser communication, which CAN include voice.

Comment: @MarcB It's more than browsers, it's peer-to-peer. Non-browser peers include native mobile apps, many enterprise desk phones actually support webrtc now (AudioCodes, I believe) as well as media servers that can then bridge/trunk to other SIP endpoints.

Answer (score 15):

The question doesn't exactly make sense because it makes the assumption that VoIP is a technical stack, but it's not - it's a concept. The concept of sending Voice (V) over (o) Internet Protocols (IP). This means that different technology stacks can be used for accessing/capturing the media, establishing connections, negotiating streams, and transmitting streams.

WebRTC is one such stack (set of APIs, methods, and standards) for VoIP.

Comment: So, basically WebRTC is any sort of communication between two peers and therefore the concept of VoIP can be implemented using this tech.
At the same time there are other techs available which can also be used to implement VoIP.

Comment: @AnimeshKumar "WebRTC is any sort of communication between two peers" - No, not "any sort" - WebRTC is a particular technical specification. The rest of your comment is accurate though.

Answer (score 5):

VOIP - Voice over Internet Protocol was a concept which came with popularity of internet. This involved using the internet to route voice telephony data, basically using existing IP infrastructure to transport audio streams without having dedicated circuit switched telephony. Over the time popular VOIP applications like Skype, Vonage and many in enterprise telephony came in. 
VOIP had two parts one signalling , basically controller part and other actual media.
Actual media usually  but not necessarily followed RTP (Real Time) protocol.  RTP could carry both voice and video. Problem with RTP has been that browsers don't support it natively and it is not secure. You usually needed some sort of plugin to have VOIP work inside browser.

With WebRTC now popular browsers like FF, Chrome and Opera support a variation of RTP which is secure and can be natively invoked. Using WebRTC and browser Javascript you can send Voice, Video and Screen (it's video only) data to any other browser, which is cool.

Answer (score 4):

**VOIP :** Voice over internet protocol uses DSL/Cable Modem voice over Wi-Fi/3G (VoWiFi/3G), voice over LTE (VoLTE), and Rich Communication Suite (RCS). VoIP is cloud-based, calls are sent as digital data and no cables are needed to send the call so any kind of Internet connection can be used to make calls and from a plethora of devices.

**Web RTC:** Web Real time communication use only OS browsers to communicate. 
WebRTC requires the use of two main component JavaScript APIs.

WebRTC is an extension of VoIP to the browser world. It can reuse the existing VoIP infrastructure with incremental upgrades. This is good news for VoIP, as adoption of WebRTC only serves to increase overall VoIP proliferation.

Also, WebRTC is ideal for low-cost browser-based contact center applications. VoIP can serve embedded operator-driven VoLTE applications. Consequently, between WebRTC and VoIP, they can support wide range of consumer and enterprise applications.